# Can't do linear regression in scikit-Learn due to "reshaping" issue

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I have a simple CSV with two columns:

1. ErrorWeek (a number for the week number in the year)
2. ErrorCount (for the number of errors in a given week)

I read the CSV data into a pandas dataframe, like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Errors.csv", sep=",")
```

df.head() shows:

```
   ErrorWeek  ErrorCount
0          1          80
1          2         118
2          3         249
3          4         397
4          5         159
```

So far so good.

Then, I create a test/train split, like this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df['ErrorWeek'], df['ErrorCount'], random_state=0)
```

No errors so far.

But, I then create a linear regression object and try to fit the data.

```
# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Here I **do** get an error: "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1)"

--

Looking at the shape of X_Test and y_Test, I get what looks like two one dimensional "arrays":

```
X_train shape: (36,)
y_train shape: (36,)
```

--

I have spent many hours trying to figure this out, but I'm new to Pandas, Python, and to scikit-learn.

I'm reading in two dimensional data, but Pandas isn't seeing that way.

What do I need to do, specifically?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
         df['ErrorWeek'], df['ErrorCount'], random_state=0)
```

will make all output arrays of one dimension because you are choosing a single column value for X and y.

Now, when you pass a one dimensional array of [n,], Scikit-learn is not able to decide that what you have passed is one row of data with multiple columns, or multiple samples of data with single column. i.e. sklearn may not infer whether its n_samples=n and n_features=1 or other way around (n_samples=1 and n_features=n) based on X data alone.

Hence it asks you reshape the 1-D data you provided to a 2-d data of shape `[n_samples, n_features]`

Now there are multiple ways of doing this.

- You can do what the scikit-learn says:

  X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,1)
  X_test = X_test.reshape(-1,1)

The 1 in the second place of reshape tells that there is a single column only and -1 is to detect the number of rows automatically for this single column.

- Do as suggested in other answers by @MaxU and @Wen

Comment: Thanks. A variation of this DID work! :)  I basically did X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(-1,1) for all the X_train, y_train, y_test. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Morkus You dont need to reshape the `y_train` and `y_test`. They should be 1-d array only.

Comment: If I comment out those two lines, I get: "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:" No idea why but the error happens on the predict method call. Thx.

Comment: @Morkus `y_train` and `y_test` are not sent to `predict()` method. Please update the code and error in method. `X_train` and `X_test` needs to be reshaped but not `y_train` and `y_test`

Answer (score 3):

change your `fit` part

```
regr.fit(X_train[:,None], y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. What does the colon mean when you have something like [:, None]?

Comment: @Morkus it just convert  array to ndarray

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df[['ErrorWeek']], df['ErrorCount'], random_state=0)
```

PS pay attention at additional square brackets: `df[['ErrorWeek']]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm a bit confused about the double square brackets and what they mean, but this too didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently sklearn wants x to be a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame because it cannot distinguish between a single feature with n samples or n features with one sample. 
Instead y can be one single column, that is a pandas.core.series.Series. 
Therefore, in your example, you should transform x to a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.

As already pointed out by @MaxU:

```
x=df[['ErrorWeek']]   # double brakets
y=df['ErrorCount']    # single brakets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`X_train.reshape(-1,1)` won't work as it's a series, you'll need to use `X_train = X_train.values.reshape(-1,1)`