# Getting an error: Reshape your data either using array

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am learning linear regression using SKlearn but I am getting this error continuously:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

mydf = pd.read_csv("Salary_Data.csv")

X = np.array(mydf["YearsExperience"])
Y = np.array(mydf["Salary"])

xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(xtrain,ytrain)  ##HERE AN ERROR ARISES
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 4.   2.2  2.9  8.2 10.5  3.   4.9  1.5  5.1  4.  10.3  4.1  3.2  2.
  9.6  6.   7.9  7.1  3.2  8.7  6.8  9.5  3.9  1.1].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't do linear regression in scikit-Learn due to "reshaping" issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761744/cant-do-linear-regression-in-scikit-learn-due-to-reshaping-issue)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you `Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1)`

```
lr.fit(xtrain,ytrain.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Scikit-Learn wants input like this:

```
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

**NOT** like this:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

That's just how it is.

Comment: Oh, it worked. Can you please let me know what was the problem? I never saw such a reshape solution. What was wrong with my data?

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks Nicolas.

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn expects your

- Independent variable(X) to have multiple features(multiple columns) Thus a 2-dimentional array.
- Dependent Variable(y) to have a single value say a class label(in case of classification) or a numerical value(in case of regression)

In your case the Independent variable(X) has only a single feature thus you have faced the issue. Which can be solved as suggested in other answer